# How to add many properties in dhtmlx gantt?

Tags: json, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

what I need to do is:

1. Load a json file.
2. Let users to tow the Gantt chart and change value.

I know this:

```
gantt.load()
```

can load json file and visualize the info on the chart.

but it only work when I use the test.json:

```
{
"data":[
    {"id":"1", "text":"Project #2", "start_date":"01-04-2013", "duration":18, 
        "progress":0.4, "open": true},
    {"id":"2", "text":"Task #1", "start_date":"02-04-2013", "duration":8, 
        "progress":0.6, "parent":"1"},
    {"id":"3", "text":"Task #2", "start_date":"11-04-2013", "duration":8, 
        "progress":0.6, "parent":"1"}
],
"links":[
    {"id":"1", "source":"1", "target":"2", "type":"1"},
    {"id":"2", "source":"2", "target":"3", "type":"0"},
    {"id":"3", "source":"3", "target":"4", "type":"0"},
    {"id":"4", "source":"2", "target":"5", "type":"2"}
]}
```

But my json is more complicated, it is an array of object.

and each object has many items( like :OrdetNum, date, start_date.... )

Below is myjson.json:

```
 {
"orderFormNumber": "1608T01CY",
"orderNumber": "1608T01CY",
"tasks": "C01*01",
"OriginalTasks": "C01",
"partUnitId": 1,
"sharedCode": "NEWABST",
"processNum": 1,
"processSequence": 1,
"initStartTime": "2018-11-18T16:50:00",
"estimatedTime": 10.833333015441895,
"initEndTime": "2018-11-19T03:39:59",
"estStartTime": "2018-11-15T14:10:00",
"estEndTime": "2018-11-17T07:19:59",
"detailSchedule": null,
"detailSchedulefromCo": null,
"qcSchedule": "2018-11-22T16:30:00",
"fifoStartTime": "2018-11-15T15:44:45",
"fifoEndTime": "2018-11-17T09:34:44",
"acoStartTime": null,
"acoEndTime": null,
"realStartTime": null,
"realEndTime": null,
"processType": "M",
"machineGroup": "M",
"machineGroupSelection": "M",
"prePart": null,
"fifoSelectedMachine": "M02",
"acoSelectedMachine": null,
"designChangesNumber": "1608T01CY",
"machineingStates": 0 }
```

But it is only one of many objects.

So how can I use gantt.load() to visualize my json file?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your object doesn't seem to match the expected data model of gantt https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__loading.html#dataproperties

I mean not the number of custom properties but the absence of mandatory properties gantt expects - **id**, **start_date**, **duration**(or end_date), **text**, **parent** (if you want nested tasks)

So unless you covert your data into something gantt can parse, I wouldn't expect anything to be displayed.

If you can't change the format returned from the server, you'll have to convert the data on the client side,

1) load the json/data object to the client https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__server_side.html#customrequestheadersandparameters

2) convert it to object gantt can understand.
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__supported_data_formats.html#json
It's important that your objects have id/start_date/end_date/duration/parent properties. You can have any number of additional properties - they will be available to the public api

3) load the result dataset into gantt using gantt.parse.
Or you can change the format on the backend and continue using gantt.load